# javascript says two values are not equal when they are (using ===)

Tags: javascript

I want to use JavaScript to determine which class/display color a number of divs(called div1, div2...up through div21) are depending on the values in schedule_array. So if 2 is in schedule_array, I want div2 to be of class clicked and if 3 is not in schedule_array, I want div3 to be of class unclicked. The problem is that my === sign seems to be giving false no matter what for this code:

```
 function setClasses()
 {
     alert("schedule array is "+schedule_array[3]);

     for(var k = 1; k<22; k++)
     {
         var name = "div" + k;
         if(contains(schedule_array, k))
         {
             document.getElementById(name).className = "clicked";
         }
         else
         {
             document.getElementById(name).className = "unclicked";
         }
     }
 }

 setClasses();


 function contains(a, obj) {
     //alert(a[3] + "for function contains");
     //alert(a.length);
     for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         document.write(a[i] + "=" + obj);
         if (a[i] === obj) {
             document.write("true,,,,,,,,");
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             document.write("false,,,,,,,,");
         }
     }

     return false;

 }
(stole this latter function from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)
```

I have no idea why, but the following code's == fails even when I am comparing the same integer to itself. For example with the code below I get output like:

```
21=21false,,,,,,
```

As you can see I've already checked to make sure schedule_array exists and has valid numbers. I have also checked to make sure both for loops are running. Finally, I confirmed that in js, even something like "5"==5 should give a true, so even if there is some weird typing going on, that shouldn't affect the outcome.

Question: what is up with this weirdness? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you posted is using `===`, not `==`, so no type conversion will happen and the number `5` will not compare as equal to the string `"5"`.

Comment: @Pointy - that's the answer - post it as an answer so you can be upvoted and this question can benefit others

Comment: @Duniyadnd yes I'm familiar with the process, but I've learned through experience that jumping in with an answer in a case like this is often met with "oops that was just a typo when I typed in the question". Hopefully the OP will clarify whether or not that is **really** the code involved.

Comment: After @Pointy : `===` means : they're exactly the same type & they have exactly the same value. While `==` means they're compareable (after type conversion). Since one is a string (`"5"`) and second is a number  (`5`), it will return `false` on `===` as they're not equal in type. Use `==` instead. **[SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)**

Comment: @Pointy - point taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.

```
function contains(a, obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

alert(contains(['1', 2, 3, 4, 5], 1));
```

Are you sure that `a` is an array?

http://jsfiddle.net/kjruk00b/

Answer (score 1):

You are using `===` which is a equality without conversion ([strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)). This means that, that although the numeric value is the same (equality) the strict equality operator is not coercing the String into a Integer to allow this comparison to happen. Switching to the non-strict equality operator `==` should solve your problem as it will convert the String into an Integer, allowing the comparison to work as you expected.

It may be worth your while looking at the [Javascript truth tables](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) for these 2 operators to get an idea for how they work.